# Resources for Display Systems in Safety Critical Embedded Systems?

Tags: embedded, real-time, safety-critical, do178-b

I am looking out for resources that can answer following questions of mine.

1. Where exactly does the display systems in SC ERTS architecture fit in.
2. What is the difference between SC display systems and normal ones?
3. What roles does hardware and software play in display systems?

I got to prepare a detailed survey of display systems for my course work. Please note that I am asking for references, sources etc and not the actual answers.

I will also be happy to see off the limb suggestions and comments.

Something useful I already found : DO 178B standard, SCADE Display Systems.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between a safety critical display system and a normal one is the same as between any safety critial system and the corresponding non-critical one: it's *safety critical*. Some failures of such a system could endanger safety. As such, these systems are designed, implemented and tested following a strict process, typically with the process itself being subject to certification (you already found the DO-178B -- for software in aeronautics, other similar standards exist for other domains. Other standards often found mentioned together with DO-178B by the makers of tools that apply to several domains are IEC 61508, EN 50128 and ISO 26262).

I'm not sure why you expect anything to apply specially to display systems... Your question may be too specific for the public here.

---

Note that generally speaking, safety is different from reliability. A safety critical system doesn't have to be perfectly reliable, only its possible failures have to be understood and to have been shown not to endanger safety. This principle applies differently in different critical domains: trains are allowed to fail in ways planes aren't.

Comment: Of course, any technology must be treated by the relevant standards, so displays are not different in this aspect. Still, the question what "dangerous" means depends on the way a system interacts with its environment. Here, safety of displays is newer (and less frequently found) than more typical examples like electronic signals (serial and non-serial interfaces) and more typical actuators/sensors. Therefore, asking such a question is perfectly legitimate.